# Using SUMIF function and the range and [sum_range] change with every cell

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have looked for this answer but haven't found anything that has worked so I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

I am using Excel 2010 and have two sheets within one workbook. The first sheet holds the majority of information regarding individual members and is where I am using the formula. The second sheet holds data regarding each members' usage. Each line represents one individual. I am trying to gather all of the instances for one individual listed in sheet two and place it in a cell in sheet one.

I have used the sumif function which works perfectly for the first individual I use it on. After that, dragging the box changes both the range and sum_range of the formula along with the criteria. I want the criteria to change to the cell in the next row but I need the range and the sum_range to remain the same for every cell. If I copy the formula from the first cell and paste it into the second row, nothing changes.

Any ideas as to how I can make the sumif formula work over the entire column without changing the range and sum_range? Or is there an easier way to do this? Please keep in mind, the second sheet will expand over time to include more and more instances which will need to be included in future calculations.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks Tim! Sorry for the duplicate question. That post helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your range is `A1:A3` so to completely lock it just change it into `$A$1:$A$3`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I locked the columns before but forgot to lock the rows. I appreciate the quick answer!